# Sanitizing user input path names

Tags: python, escaping, sanitization

Using Python 2.6 on Windows I have a function that needs to accept a path name as an arg. I'm running into issues when certain specific paths are passed.

```
C:\users\bob\something.png    #this is handled no prob.
C:\users\bob\nothing.png      #this generates a WindowsError
C:\users\bob\test.png         #this also generates a WindowsError
```

What I'm gathering is that the `\n` in the "nothing" path is being interpreted as a new line, and the `\t` in the "test" path is being interpreted as a tab.

If I print out the path names, that's what appears to be happening.

```
print os.path.abspath("C:\users\bob\nothing.png")
C:\users\bob
othing.png
```

Same for the 'test' path, except a tab instead of a new line.

The only thing I've come up with so far is to do a check to see if `\n` or `\t` are in the path name, and then handle it accordingly, but there must assuredly be a better way.

```
if '\n' in path_name:
    #escape slash, move on
```

What would a better way be?

Comment: This has nothing to do with paths; it seems to be about string quoting in Python source files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print os.path.abspath(r"C:\users\bob\nothing.png")
```

may be what your looking for ...

although user input should automatically be escaping the slash ...

```
>>> a = raw_input("Enter Path:")
Enter Path:C:\www\a\nothing.jpg
>>> a
'C:\\www\\a\\nothing.jpg'
```

as you can see from this example user input is indeed escaped

Comment: For some reason, input isn't automatically escaping the slash when the slash is preceding a 't' or a 'n' - there are likely other cases where this will happen.  Not sure if it's a Windows issue, or a Python issue, but forcing to a raw string did the trick, will accept in 9 more mins....

Comment: @Andenthal all the backslashes should be escaped.  Not just the ones that will form "special" characters

Comment: I know they should be, but they aren't: `print os.path.getsize("C:\users\bob\test.png")` returns:  `C:\\users\\bob\test.png  "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"`  Why the first two are escaped, the the third not?

Comment: how are you getting your user input?

Comment: It comes from another module, that gets it from an xml file.